# Distribution of a double-sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have some random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ that are normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma$. I am trying to model a function of these variables that includes a double-sum of their difference:
$$ \sum_{n, m\neq n}^{N,N} (X_n - X_m)^2 $$

I tried to model this sum as a chi-squared distribution with $(N^2-N)$ degrees of freedom (the -N comes from including every term except the terms where $n=m$). Then this sum should have mean $2\sigma^2 (N^2-N)$ and variance $8 \sigma^4 (N^2-N)$. But when I try to confirm that numerically in MATLAB, I find the variance is much larger. I assume this must be because the terms of the sum are not independent, they are using the same variables $X_n$ so they are correlated. But I don't know a way to include the correlations. Is there a neat way to evaluate the distribution of this sum?

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_N)$?

Comment: Expand the square and work on each term. Do you know the covariance or correlation between the $X_i$? It might be easier if you note $(X_n - X_m)^2=0$ when $n=m$ and would not add to the sum

Comment: Thanks for the responses. William, the distribution of $(X_1,…,X_N)$ is normal with 0 mean and standard deviation $\sigma$. Henry, each $X_1$ is independent. But I think the terms of the sum must become correlated because they are N^2-N terms composes of only N, X terms.  I tried expanding the square and the two $X_n^2$ terms are easy with a chi-squared distribution. But the cross-term $X_n X_m$ has the same problem as this sum, it can't be modeled by simple product distribution rule.

Comment: Did you compare your  $8 \sigma^4 (N^2-N)$ to your observations? I suspect they may be out by a factor of $N$ so $8\sigma^4 (N^3-N^2)$ could perform better

Comment: @Henry Yes, the extra factor of N matches simulations almost exactly! But where is extra factor of N coming from?